# Usage of MakeExpression

Tags: input-forms

I would like to use MakeExpression to be able to work with a specific Input.The Input is always a decimal number like -0,45666 or 0,120 (there could be an overbar indicating periodicity).
MakeExpression should tramsform an input of -0.45333 to a structure NUM [s,i,k,l] where:

- s...sign
- i...0 (Integer before the comma)
- k...45
- l...333(periodic part with overbar)

The cell shows: Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{RowBox[{"-", "0.45"}], AdjustmentBox[     OverscriptBox["666", "_"],BoxMargins->{{-0.159204, 0}, {0, 0}}], " "}]], "Input",...

I know that I have to analyse the cell to look up how the boxes are structured. However I´m failing setting up the NUM-structure on the right side.

```
e.g.(pseudocode): 
MakeExpression[RowBox[{RowBox[{"s", "i"}], 
AdjustmentBox[OverscriptBox["l", "_"],
BoxMargins->{{-0.159204, 0}, {0, 0}}], " "}]], "Input",... := 
MakeExpression[RowBox["NUM",s,i,l...]'''
```

Does anybody has an idea, why? It has to be done with MakeExpression...

Comment: I do not see what you intend and why you want to use MakeExpression. An input like 0.120 will be interpreted without further ado. An input like -0,45666 is never periodic because how would you distinguish it  from -0,45666... Therefore, to input a periodic part, you already need the overbar in the input. No MakeEXpression needed.